# Visual Studio: How do you set your git username and password?

Tags: git, visual-studio

To my surprise, I cannot find this from googling.  I'm using 2017 Community Edition and when I try to push, it says, `failed to acquire credentials.`  I can't find any place to set these in visual studio, though.  Where can I set the git username and password in visual studio 2017 Community Edition?

I'm using https authentication.

Comment: How is your git installed? Did you install it yourself, did you use the visual studio installer to do it for you or did you install a visual studio extension for git? Also do you want to connect to github or gitlab or one of your own git servers?

Comment: I installed it myself.  Actually I have the lastest cygwin and windows version.  I have not installed a VS studio extension.  Should I need to?  There are already settings for how to configure git.  I want to connect to a gitlab copy.